# Jquery Load element page works with everything except videos

Tags: jquery, video

Here is the code

```
$(function() {
    if(location.hash) $("#content_inload").load(location.hash.substring(1) + ' #content_inload'); 
    $("#nav a").click(function() {
        $("#content_inload").load(this.hash.substring(1) + ' #content_inload');
    });
});
```

For some reason it will load everything but will not load the jw video player. However if I ask it to load the entire page rather than just '#content_inload' it will load the video even though that page has no head section, no scripts and is no more than the content inside '#content_inload'. I can only assume that the JW player adds a line of code to the bottom of the top of the content, but cannot find what that line is.

Comment: Samples at http://www.divethegap.com/update/community/videos/ (click on the test videos).

Comment: what is exactly in the loaded page ?

Comment: <div id="content_inload">
<?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<?php the_content(); ?>
      <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
</div>

(and nothing more) All works fine if I tell it to load the whole page rather than just '#content_inload' but '#content_inload' is the whole page. Just a sample to test the problem this is not how the finished result will be.

Comment: What is this "jw video player" you're talking about?

Comment: there occurs an error(inloader.js, line 15, **it** is undefined). Could you first fix this error to exclude dependencies.

Comment: It is just an embedded video streaming off another part of the site. The scritps to make it work are <script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2.2/swfobject.js?ver=3.0.1'></script> The single file will work but it appears these scripts do not pass through the jquery load

Comment: Line 15 and the fade effect has been removed. Still not working though.

Answer (score 1):

If you see the source code of jquery about the `.load()` method they do

```
...
self.html( 
    selector ?
    // Create a dummy div to hold the results
    jQuery("<div>")
        // inject the contents of the document in, removing the scripts
        // to avoid any 'Permission Denied' errors in IE
        .append(res.responseText.replace(rscript, ""))

        // Locate the specified elements
        .find(selector) :

    // If not, just inject the full result
    res.responseText 
);
...
```

So if a selector is provided (as is in your case) they remove the script to avoid Permission Denied errors in IE.

You will need to imitate this code using the jquery [`.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) method

something like

```
$("#nav a").click(function() {
    $.get( this.hash.substring(1), function(response){
      var dummy = $('<div>').append( response ).find('#content_inload');
      $("#inload_container").html(dummy);
    } );
});
```

Also note that i have used the `#inload_container` as the target element as you were inserting the `#content_inload` into itself, in effect duplicating  ..

---

**Update**

Well after your comment i tried the following that worked

```
$("#nav a").click(function() {
    $.get( this.hash.substring(1), function(response){
      $("#inload_container").empty().append(response).find('>*:not(#content_inload)').remove();
    } );
});
```

Seems that there might be an issue when you create script elements in in-memory jquery objects ? (*cant be sure of the reason*)

In your specific case the above solution will work, but it is not very elegant, in the sense that it adds to the DOM everything returned from the ajax call and it then filters out the stuff we do not want..

It might be better altogether to just alter your actual video page (*the one loaded from ajax*) and do a normal `.load()` without filtering anything out..

Comment: Thanks for telling me about the IE problem. Have implemented your code but still the video will not load. The video only loads if the script does not define an element to load.